# References for training BERT-like models from scratch

Tags: references, natural-language, transformers, pre-training

As the title of the question suggests, I'm interested in training a BERT-like model (and then use it to make some experiments on *text-similarity*).

**Question:** Could you share some references on the process of training a BERT model from scratch?

**Observations:**

1. A good reference to understand what do I mean by *'training from scratch'* is something similar to what is done for the complete *encoder-decoder* training section in the article: ['The Annotated Transformer'](https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html).
2. I'm particularly interested in the conceptual understanding of how a BERT-like model is trained.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could strengthen your question by clarifying what you’d like to know that isn’t described in the original BERT paper.